# How can I deploy a html website using Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-resource-manager, azure-web-app-service

I've got a website (basic html) and I want to deploy it using Azure Resource manager.  It doesn't have a visual studio sln file and I don't want to create one.

I've found this tutorial for an angular website that does something along the lines that I am trying to do.  http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/how-to-publish-an-angularjs-website-with-azure-resource-manager-templates/

The problem I want to solve is that I have the Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2015) 2.8.2 which allows me to add resources to my resource group project.  The tutorial writes everything itself, rather than use visual studio to create the resources.

Does any one know how to do this?

I've got my application to build the website using a website.publishproj (found at the tutorial) so I have my zip file,  what I am now lacking, is how to upload the zip file to azure using the already existing powershell that comes with the 2.8.2 SDK.

So far i've added the below code under the Import-Module statement:

```
C:\"Program Files (x86)"\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe 'C:\Source\website.publishproj' /T:Package /P:PackageLocation=".\dist" /P:_PackageTempDir="packagetmp"
$websitePackage = "C:\Source\dist\website.zip"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're ultimate goal here is the ability to simply deploy and changes to the Azure Web App, one solution is to setup automated deployment from a local Git repository into an Azure Web App.  Firstly, you'd create the RG in the Azure portal then configure Continuous Deployment.  You can then use something like Visual Studio Code to trigger the deployment from any code changes.

Good run through here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-app-using-vscode/

Assuming your website is under source control eg. GitHub - you can use an ARM template to point at the GitHub repo, so when it creates a new website it will automatically pull the content into your newly created site.  Great walkthrough here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-arm-from-github-provision/ or just the code can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-web-app-github-deploy.

You can use Azure CLI from non-Microsoft world to deploy eg. 
azure group deployment create...

If this has helped, please mark as answered.

Comment: Hi Buster, thanks for answering the question.  I'm looking to deploy a website that isn't within the world of microsoft.  the tutorial talks of deploying a asp.net 5 website and i'm looking to avoid that.  Do you have any ideas on that?

Comment: ASP.NET 5 is Open Source :)